# Spring boot trying to update different database then specified

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

My application.properties look like this

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

My application-dev.properties look like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.initialSize=3

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

allowed.origins=*
```

Now there exists a table `user` in this db as well as another db. When hibernate tries to update the schema it says `Table found secondDB.user`.
Then after a few lines of log it says `Table does not exists firstDB.user` and there is a error log that schema cannot be updated. I initially thought it was maybe because of spring-boot-dev-tools that it has cached some information as I am separately working on both databases but even after removing it the problem exists. core pom.xml is this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If someone has seen the same issue or can help me out as to why this may be happening?

EDIT:

```
2016-07-10 02:21:42.692  INFO 501 --- [           main] i.s.b.SilverCubeApplicationStarter       : Starting SilverCubeApplicationStarter on NIKHILs-MBP.lan with PID 501 (/***/target/classes started by ** in /***/)
2016-07-10 02:21:42.696 DEBUG 501 --- [           main] i.s.b.SilverCubeApplicationStarter       : Running with Spring Boot v1.3.5.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.6.RELEASE
2016-07-10 02:21:42.696  INFO 501 --- [           main] i.s.b.SilverCubeApplicationStarter       : The following profiles are active: dev
2016-07-10 02:21:42.772  INFO 501 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@33cb5951: startup date [Sun Jul 10 02:21:42 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-10 02:21:45.661  INFO 501 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb628307] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-10 02:21:46.685  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-10 02:21:46.724  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-07-10 02:21:46.726  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-07-10 02:21:47.020  INFO 501 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
016-07-10 02:21:47.020  INFO 501 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4256 ms
2016-07-10 02:21:47.253  INFO 501 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-10 02:21:47.264  INFO 501 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*](*/adding this to avoid comment)
2016-07-10 02:21:47.855  INFO 501 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-07-10 02:21:47.876  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-07-10 02:21:48.037  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-07-10 02:21:48.039  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-07-10 02:21:48.041  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-07-10 02:21:48.710  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Sun Jul 10 02:21:48 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Jul 10 02:21:48 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Jul 10 02:21:48 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2016-07-10 02:21:49.022  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-07-10 02:21:49.174  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-07-10 02:21:49.785  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-07-10 02:21:49.785  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-07-10 02:21:49.788  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-07-10 02:21:49.965  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: storefront.user
2016-07-10 02:21:49.966  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [password, updated_at, phone, name, created_at, id, authorities, email]
2016-07-10 02:21:49.966  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2016-07-10 02:21:49.966  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [uk_ob8kqyqqgmefl0aco34akdtpe, primary]
2016-07-10 02:21:50.003 ERROR 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table user add column status varchar(255)
2016-07-10 02:21:50.005 ERROR 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : Table 'silvercube.user' doesn't exist
2016-07-10 02:21:50.005  INFO 501 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-07-10 02:21:51.205  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/users],methods=[GET]}" onto public in.silvercube.backend.UIBean<java.util.List<in.silvercube.backend.user.repository.UserEntity>> in.silvercube.backend.user.controller.UserController.viewAllUsers()
2016-07-10 02:21:51.206  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/users/test],methods=[POST]}" onto public in.silvercube.backend.UIBean<in.silvercube.backend.user.repository.UserEntity> in.silvercube.backend.user.controller.UserController.createNewEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2016-07-10 02:21:51.207  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/users],methods=[POST],consumes=[multipart/form-data]}" onto public in.silvercube.backend.UIBean<in.silvercube.backend.user.repository.UserEntity> in.silvercube.backend.user.controller.UserController.createNewEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)
2016-07-10 02:21:51.208  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/users/login],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public in.silvercube.backend.UIBean<in.silvercube.backend.user.dto.LoginResponse> in.silvercube.backend.user.controller.UserController.login(in.silvercube.backend.user.dto.LoginObject)
2016-07-10 02:21:51.214  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-07-10 02:21:51.214  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-07-10 02:21:51.367  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@33cb5951: startup date [Sun Jul 10 02:21:42 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-10 02:21:52.249  INFO 501 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-10 02:21:52.359  INFO 501 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-10 02:21:52.365  INFO 501 --- [           main] i.s.b.SilverCubeApplicationStarter       : Started SilverCubeApplicationStarter in 11.119 seconds (JVM running for 12.546)
2016-07-10 02:22:32.685  INFO 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-07-10 02:22:32.685  INFO 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-07-10 02:22:32.704  INFO 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
2016-07-10 02:22:32.727 DEBUG 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] in.silvercube.backend.user.Interceptor   :  ****  Request received: OPTIONS on /users/login, 
2016-07-10 02:22:32.761 DEBUG 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] in.silvercube.backend.user.Interceptor   :  ****  Request received: POST on /users/login, 
Hibernate: select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.created_at as created_2_0_, userentity0_.email as email3_0_, userentity0_.password as password4_0_, userentity0_.status as status5_0_, userentity0_.updated_at as updated_6_0_ from user userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=?
2016-07-10 02:22:33.127  WARN 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2016-07-10 02:22:33.127 ERROR 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'silvercube.user' doesn't exist
2016-07-10 02:22:33.137  WARN 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2016-07-10 02:22:33.138  WARN 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'silvercube.user' doesn't exist
2016-07-10 02:22:33.146 ERROR 501 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'silvercube.user' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1930) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.findByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at in.silvercube.backend.user.service.UserService.getUserByEmail(UserService.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at in.silvercube.backend.user.controller.UserController.login(UserController.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

The current state of my database is :
 - The db 'storefront' has been created and its schema is populated
 - The db 'silvercube' is created (but no schema) and once the application runs, hibernate tries to update schema and create appropriate tables which results in the mentioned stacktrace.
 - Reference : firstDb=silvercube, secondDb=storefront

```
// The entity class is almost same in both projects (with some differences of attributes).
@Entity(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {}
```

Comment: you may try to explicitly add  spring.datasource.initialize=false

Comment: do you have an import.sql file ? and/or schema.sql/data.sql ?

Comment: Nopes. No sql files are present either for schema or data. Maybe I will try with initialize as false and see if i see such behaviour.

Comment: Just throwing ideas: are your entities annotated with a schema name ?

Comment: following my previous comment, do you have something like @Table(name = "user", schema="secondDB") ? Perhaps you could post your entity + the error log ?

Comment: No annotation for schema name. I have posted my entity and error log. Entitites have few more annotation for id,generatedvalue,column,prepersist,preupdate

Comment: Do you have a hibernate.cfg.xml or orm.xml ?

Comment: nopes. pure java/annotation based config.